# Is there a global flow of income?

Tags: macroeconomics, money-supply, international-economics, imf

If I understand the [circular flow of income](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56527/where-is-the-central-bank-in-the-circular-flow-of-income) correctly, we can visualize money moving around the country in exchange for goods and services. Sources of money are the central bank ([MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monetary_base)) and the financial sector (everything else). I found this very helpful in understanding how things function.

Is there a similar visualization for the global economy, including sources of "global money" if that's a thing?

As far as I understand the economic actors would include:

- individual countries, including their:

  - central bank money (MB)
  - commercial bank money
  - foreign reserves
- IMF
- World Bank

So I'm trying to understand something more than my naive sense that "every country can trade with every other country":

[image: Complete graph of five nodes]

Comment: The "balance of payments" seems to be part of the answer.

Comment: Also "international monetary system" specifically the current "Washington Consensus"